# Warning "The OLE DB Source. Outputs[OLE DB Source Output] references an external data type that cannot be mapped to the data flow task datatype"

Tags: ssis, ssms

I am new to SSIS and I need proper guidance to solve one problem. I get a warning in SSIS "he OLE DB Source. Outputs[OLE DB Source Output] references an external data type that cannot be mapped to the data flow task datatype. The data flow task type DT_WSTR will be used instead"

Also, this particular integration doesn't run properly and I have to run it manually using the option of "executing package". Is that due to the warning mentioned above?

Comment: What is the `data type` of the column in the source. This is a warning which you can ignore if you are getting expected results in the column. I am not sure what you meant in the second paragraph. What do you mean by "doesn't run properly"? This warning message should not result in not running the package.

Comment: Hi Amit, I am new to this. How can i check the data type? In second paragraph, i wanted to say that does this warning affects my package execution?

Comment: Edit your OLEDB source and go to the Columns page. You should be able to see the data type of the column you need.

Comment: Hi Amit, I just researched on it and my data type is unicode string [DT_WTSR]. I checked through advanced editor -> input and output properties tab

Comment: What is the data type of the column in the source database?

Comment: I already replied its Unicode String [DT_WTSR]

Comment: That's the datatype which SSIS has converted it to. What is the actual datatype. You will have to look at the table definition in the source database.

Comment: And what is the datatype for each of these columns? Basically one of the columns have a datatype which SSIS doesn't recognize and hence converting it to DT_WTSR.

Comment: Hi Amit, the source database has 6 external columns: Name : Unicode string [DT_WSTR], ID: Four byte signed integer [DT_14], datekey: Four byte signed integer [DT_14], fulldate: database date [DT_DBDATE], memberstatus : unicode string [DT_WSTR], verificationstatus : unicode string [DT_WSTR], net : currency [DT_CY], totalmembers: four byte signed integer [DT_14]

Comment: you are still looking at the package. These are SSIS datatypes. You need to log in to the database and see the table definition there.

Comment: so i checked the table in database and it  has following columns Name : nvarchar (50), ID: int, datekey: int, fulldate: date, memberstatus : nvarchar2(50), verificationstatus : nvarchar2(50), net: money, totalmembers: int

Comment: Your `nvarchar2(50)` is the culprit here. What is your source database - Oracle? SSIS is converting it to [DT_WSTR]. Look at this length of the column and they should be same.

Comment: yes its the same. How can I solve it?

Comment: There is nothing to solve here. SSIS has solved it for you by converting it to DT_WSTR. You just need to ensure that there is no truncation in the values by checking the length of the column in the OLEDB Source properties.

Comment: thanks a lot for help!